# Categories off-set

Tags: php, mysql

I am about to build an SQL database and I need to get it right instead of making mistakes and fixing them down the line which is why I am here...

I will have main categories and sub categories to them, I need to know weather it'd be best to store the sub categories in the same tables as the main but just offset them for example:

```
Protein | Fat Loss | (two main categories)
Whey    | example  | (these would be linked)
```

I was thinking of designing the table like this:

```
cid, name, lcid (linked number)
```

So if lcid is set to 0 then its a main category but if its got a number relating to a cid in it then its a sub-category.

Then I would use php to link them together and display them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're talking about is called an [Adjacency List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list).  It is useful for creating a hierarchy that changes often but doesn't have to provide much information.  If, however, your hierarchy changes less often, but has to answer questions like "how many siblings/ancestors does this node have", a Nested Set model will do you better. Have a look [here](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) for a description of pros and cons.